# Is it possible to return a more derived type from a less deriving type?

Tags: c++, inheritance

Take for example a base class called Object with a ToString method.

```
    class Object
    {
     public:
        String ToString() const
        {
            //Base functionality returns a string such as "Object".
        }
    }
```

The ToString method returns a String which inherits from Object.

```
    class String : public Object
    {
     public:
        String ToString() const //Override
        {
            //Return actual string representation here.
        }
    }
```

Here is the problem. When compiling Object, String at that point is an incomplete
type. Obviously because it isn't defined until AFTER Object. It's a top to bottom
problem.

Is there a way to return the type String from Object?

C++20's modules provide no help. At least no help i am aware of. If you put
Object and String into respective modules, you end up with module file mapping
errors. Basically, the same problem as before. You can't make Object aware of
String.

In a newer language this problem doesn't exist. A type not yet known is put aside
until it becomes known, then the pieces put together.

Would there be a way to achieve similar functionality in C++?

Comment: This actually seems more an XY problem rather than a matter of forward declaration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a textbook case of forward declarations.

```
    class String;

    class Object
    {
     public:
        String ToString() const;
    };
```

After the forward declaration, when both `String` and `Object` are fully defined, you can now define `Object::ToString`, and do whatever it does (either as an inline definition, or in a discrete translation unit).

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/nf5noobff)